# Validation is working too well

Tags: java, validation

I have this validation to check that user input is not blank and is only letters. If it's blank, it catches it, and if if includes digits it also catches it. If I input the 2 characters it asks for, however, it doesn't go through. I'm not sure how to go about this.

```
private static boolean isValidSt(String aSt) {
    boolean result = false;

    try {
        if (aSt.length() == 2) {
            result = true;
        } else if (aSt.length() != 2) {
            result = false;
        }
        for (int i=0; i <aSt.length();){
            if (!Character.isLetter(i));{
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfex) {
        if (aSt == null) System.exit(0);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        if (aSt == null) System.exit(0);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Please don't use sarcasm in the title be specific about your problem. Also, what is your question?

Comment: I don't fully understand your question, but it seems to me that removing that `return true;` from the middle and relying on the `return result;` at the end would give you something that correctly traps the case when the number of characters isn't 2.

Comment: my question is that the validator is checking both the digits entered and blank input but if i put CA for state it doesnt move to the next question for my program which would be "Enter address"

Comment: An `i++` in the `for` loop would be a welcome addition if you don't want to get stuck in an endless loop.

Comment: when i add i++ it says its dead code.

Comment: It says that because you always return false right away. Hence, you never reach the `i++` statement, so it is indeed dead code.

Comment: also `Character.isLetter(i)` is always going to be false since a number is not a letter, you might want aSt.charAt(i).isLetter() or something more like that (my java is rusty)

Answer (score 4):

One problem that I can see right of the bat is this:

```
if (!Character.isLetter(i));{
    return false;
}
```

That semi-colon after your if does not belong there. After checking your conditional statement, if it was true, it will execute until the semi-colon. The `return false;` isn't part of the `if` and will ALWAYS be executed.

As David Wallice rightly pointed out, you also never increment the counter in your `for`-loop, so were it not the case that the program always returned with false in the first iteration, it would indeed get stuck in an eternal loop. A very commonly used syntax for `for`-loops would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < string.length(); i++) { }
```

A third and final note from me, this time nothin that would give an error, just good form:

You use `System.exit(0);` to exit the program as result of an exception. The zero you pass as an argument is usually only used when the program shuts down normally. This is a crash as a result of an error, so I'd use 1 or something.

Comment: The for loop also never increments

Comment: i added the increments but still doesnt work i am not sure where i would but the return false; either

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could use StringUtils methods,  [isBlank](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isBlank%28java.lang.CharSequence%29) and [isAlpha](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#isAlpha%28java.lang.CharSequence%29), for validate what you need